# PDF files open with a dark overlay?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, pdf-reader

Windows XP
Adobe Acrobat Pro 9 with the latest updates

This is one of my user's machines.  They have basic user rights, non-admin.  Opening a PDF file renders the document, but with a dark overlay.  It is also missing every other page on every document the user tries to open.

What I've done:
Repair install of Acrobat - **No change**

Uninstall + Reinstall + Updates - **No change**

Run acrobat.exe as Administrator with my credentials - **PDF opens with NO issues.**

Transfered PDF to another basic user, **who opened it with no issues.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user has accidentally enabled a setting in which that overlay has been activated. Honestly I forgot how to find that setting, but I assure you I've seen it before and if you can manage to set her pdf reader to default settings it will go away.

When you are uninstalling and reinstalling that is not helping the issue because the preferences for that software is still saved locally thus you won't see a change. Hope you find that option :)

Comment: Found the answer is to delete the entire Acrobat key from teh registry.  Scary to do, but it auto generates a new one on the next load.  Key is located here:HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Adobe\Adobe Acrobat

Comment: I knew it was something like that. Cool stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to uncheck the "Use 2D graphics acceleration" option in Edit → Preferences → Page display → Rendering.